# Catch / cancel an unhandled exception whilst debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to stop / handle and exception in visual studio without modifying the source code?

For example, whilst running the application if an unhanded exception is thrown, I wish to break in visual studio but gobble up the exception so the calling code is not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to simply let the exception be thrown, and then set the next line to be executed to be the line after the exception is thrown.

Either using right click > "set next statement". Or drag the yellow arrow downwards.

You may wish to also use the immediate window, locals etc to "fix" whatever was broken / the reason for the exception to be thrown.